# "Is he a director of this company?" or "Is he director of this company?"

Tags: articles

In these sentences:

> "Is he a director of this company?"

> "Is he director of this company?"

Why don't we use the article 'a' in this question? Is there any workaround?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with "Is he a director of this company?"  if it's a company with a board of directors.

Comment: AND *Is he **the** director of this company?* Which even more strongly than your article-less version implies there's only ***one*** director.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the company have more than one director? If yes, I would say

> Is he one of the directors of this company?

When you ask in general (without "of this company"), you need the indefinite article ***a***, as when we ask about any profession:

> Is he ***a*** director? (Is he a musician/teacher/writer?)

If the company has only one director, then you need the definite article ***the***:

> Is he the director of this company?

Neither "Is he a director of this company?" nor "Is he director of this company?" sound very common, but you might come across the second one in certain situations.

Answer (score 0):

We don't use any article when one man holds only one position at a time & the name of the post/position is used predicatively.

> *"Is he director of this company?"*

But when it is a title for person, use 'the' :

> *"The director of this company has come."*

Comment: We used to also omit the article for family relationships — “I am Leif, son of Erik” — but that has a rather archaic sound now.  For some reason, with family relationships you are allowed to the definite article — “Is Malia the daughter of Barack?” — even though the indefinite is clearly called for.

Answer (score 0):

"Is he a director of this company?" -- if there is more than one director.

If there is only one, it would be --  "Is he the director of this company?"